# How can I drop 15 V down to 3.7 V to drive a motor?

Tags: motor, dc-dc-converter

I have a little DC fan motor that is rated at 3.7 V and 100 mA.

I’m going to mount it on the back of a wagon on my little boy’s train set and turn it into a fan train.

The DC controller output is 15 V maximum.

I need a way to drop the voltage across the motor to 3.7 V.  How do I do this? I’m guessing insert a resistor, but how can I know what size to choose?

I’m thinking if the motor is rated at 3.7 V and 100 mA, the motor’s resistance is 37 ohms, but when I measure its resistance with my multimeter it only measures 1.4 ohms for some reason.

Comment: 16 diodes in series...

Comment: Re *"only measures 1.4 ohms"*: I would have expected the answers to mention (and/or explain) [back-EMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-electromotive_force) (or whatever the correct terminology is).

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use a fan with a higher voltage rating. Why not use a 5 V or 12 V fan? It would certainly be more energy-efficient - having to drop almost 12 V, from 15V, just to power a tiny fan seems rather wasteful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *But when I measure it’s resistance with my multimeter it only measures
> 1.4ohms for some reason*

That's the DC resistance of the rotor winding and, because it's not spinning you can also call it the "stalled" resistance of the motor so, if you applied 3.7 volts to the motor and locked the rotor/armature, you would see about 2.6 amps (give or take).

> *I’m thinking if the motor is rated at 3.7V and 100mA, the motor’s
> resistance is 37ohms*

That would be the equivalent resistance of the motor when it is running at nominal or full-load.

> *I need a way to drop the voltage across the motor to 3.7V. How do I do
> this?*

Using a resistor to drop the voltage isn't going to work; you need to use a voltage regulator and one that can survive the stall conditions and start-up conditions (pretty much the same). But, not any old voltage regulator. For instance, a linear voltage regulator that can provide 3.7 volts at the stall current of 2.6 amps would need to drop 15 volts minus 3.7 volts between input and output and, this would cause a power dissipation of 11.3 volts × 2.6 amps = 29 watts and would fry.

So, your options are to use a switching voltage regulator or, just power the track with 3.7 volts using the supply that previously powered the motor when used as a fan in the previous application.

Answer (score 9):

You need to find out if your motor is a brushed DC or a brushless one. If brushless, you can't safely drop the voltage with just a resistor since the unloaded voltage will remain 15 V and potentially fry the inverter inside the motor. The Zener and DC/DC would however work.

Assuming brushed motor, dropping 15 V down to 3.7 V with 100 mA would require a (15-3.7)/0.1 = 113 ohm resistor. However, a motor is not a continuous 100 mA load. With just a fan connected to it, you can probably get away with it by measuring the actual load and adjusting the resistance accordingly.

But if we assume it does draw 100 mA, we are talking about 1.13 W of dissipation. I would go with a 3 W rated resistor in order to keep the temperature rise to decent levels.

Another option would be to use Zener diodes to drop ~11 V. Make sure they are rated for the power dissipation.

Best but most expensive option would be a DC-DC converter to give out 3.7 V.

Least messy solution would be to get yourself a 15 V motor and use it directly.

Comment: I would strongly advise against dropping the voltage with just a resistor... That's one very inefficient way to do so...

Comment: "Best but **most expensive** option" Here I disagree. Lots of step-down adjustable DC/DC converters module up to 3A max load are cheaply available even on Amazon. You can get one for about a couple dollar in a pack of 5 or 10. A power resistor or a string of diodes or a power Zener could well cost way more, and be less reliable and more bulky, not to speak the time to set up.

Comment: @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine About 40 cent if you buy one. Cheaper to cobble together some 1/2 W ones. https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/koa-speer-electronics-inc/MOS3CT631R101J/15276353

Comment: @winny Yep, that's definitely an option.

Answer (score 6):

The little fan motor is likely a brushless direct-current motor (BLDC). It consist of an actual stator windings, a permanent rotor magnet and some inverter electronics built in that controls the windings to get the proper frequency and phase of an AC voltage and current.

As a consequence, one could not get a meaningful measurement of resistance - you are measuring a dc-input of a non-working complex electronics.

In order to reliably power a BLDC motor from a model train power supply will require a voltage regulator and, probably, also a rectifier if the trains are made to run in both directions.

A resistor will not do - the motor expects to be able to turn its windings on and off and in the "off" moments the voltage will go all the way to 15V. Not good for something that is designed to run off a 3.7V.

---

A brushed motor will also show wrong measurement, but for a different reason. Its electrical properties depend on the rotation rate and load. So in order to get the actual resistance, you need to power it with its rated voltage and current.

Here, a resistor could work. Mostly. The brushes will run somewhat sparky, but a capacitor in parallel to the motor could fix that.

The best resistor you can use for this is a 12V lightbulb of 10W or 12W or 15W power. (It's resistance can't be reliably measured either and it also varies by applied voltage, but don't worry - it works)

Answer (score 4):

If you are sure your fan can be powered with a 3.7V DC constant voltage source, and its current rating is less than 1A or so, your best bet is to purchase a little adjustable DC/DC step-down (buck) converter module like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PDGG84B) (the first I found on Amazon):

[image]

They cost a couple dollars (in pack of 5 or 10) and they have lots of advantages:

- Their output voltage is easily adjusted to your desired 3.7V.
- As long as the input is a couple volts higher than the output, the exact input voltage doesn't matter much.
- They are small and quite rugged.
- They are highly efficient: they are rated for 3A max or so, thus if your output current is well below that limit they will barely get warm.
- This also means less current drawn from the input source. You can think of them very roughly as DC transformers: if the voltage is reduced by 3 at the output, the current drawn at the input is also reduced by 3 (very roughly, losses not counted in). In other words, \$P_{OUT} \approx P_{IN}\$.
- They are easy to use, so you don't need complex calculations to compute the exact value of a resistor or the max power rating for that resistor or drop diodes (calculations which will depend on input voltage, too).
- You are less likely to hurt the kid, since they don't dissipate much power (given your situation) so they don't risk getting hot.
- You could well end-up spending less than other solutions (and wasting less time in setting it up): a single power resistor could well cost the same or more (depending on wattage). Ditto for a string of diodes or a power Zener diode. And these solutions *will* get hot unless you use oversized parts.

The only disadvantage is that usually they are sold in packs of at least 5, you may end-up never using the other four if you don't usually play with electronics. However they are very useful modules to have at your disposal when doing little hobby projects. In the end YMMV.

As others have said, you need to account for stall current if the fan could become stuck (that's a hard limit on the max current your fan could draw from the module).

If the stall current is greater than the max current rating of the module (that one is ~3A) you have to choose a module with higher current rating (cheap modules with 5A are also widely available). More than 5A max becomes increasingly expensive, though.

Anyway, such modules usually employ an IC which is protected from overloads (electrically and thermally), so they are inherently safer than using a resistor or other "low-tech" solutions, should the
the fan become stalled or mechanically overloaded.

The one I posted is based on the [LM2596 IC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf)(adjustable version). From the datasheet you can see it is rated for input voltages up to 40V and a 3A output current, with thermal and overload protections. Output voltages are lower than input voltages and can be set down to 1.2V.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but would the output be a constant voltage with that?  What I really need is something that converts a variable input voltage 0-15V to an output in proportion between 0-3.7V.  I.e. output is 3.7/15=25% of the input so we can make the fan go faster and slower as the voltage across the tracks changes.

Comment: @Apc123 You didn't state this requirement in your question. The very title of your question says the opposite and you say: "I need a way to drop the voltage across the motor ***to 3.7 V***", there is no mention of you wanting to *scale down proportionally* a voltage. If you don't provide exact requirements you are wasting a person's time by making them chasing red herrings.

Comment: Anyone who has ever owned or operated a toy train set knows you vary the speed of the trains by varying the voltage across the rails.  I would have thought that this was obvious.

Comment: @Apc123 Even if this were obvious, the output of the controller is the input of your "fan adapter circuit". It is not stated anywhere in your post that you wanted a *variable **output***. As most EE would understand from the sentence I cited, it seemed you wanted something that adapted the (possibly) variable output of your train regulator to a fixed 3.7V voltage. ...

Comment: @Apc123 ... Moreover you can't assume any people on this site knows how an electric toy train is powered, this is not a site specific for toy trains owners. Here you ask about electronics, not toy trains. Any specifics of your application is up to you to specify, as well as any requirements. ...

Comment: @Apc123. ...  In addition, this site is not a generic electronic forum, any question asked is not here for the sole benefit of the person asking, but for the community at large, so the question must be clear, well-specified and self-contained. Any assumption outside the realm of electronics make the question not well-specified. Please, reread the [help] center about that.

Comment: Ok, you’ve made yourself clear.  Thanks to all those who tried to help and made me feel welcome.